# Java if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

is there something wrong with this if statement i am trying to make a swing login system??? thanks :)

```
 public void login()
    {
           String username = loginField.getText();
           char[] password = loginPass.getPassword();
           if (username.equals("test") && password.equals("test"))
           {
                    System.out.println("logged in");
           }
    }
```

Comment: Your requirement is actually not clear. That's why cannot tell if it's working the correct way.

Comment: Never hardcode some username/password in the sourcecode, even for testing purpose. The removement of those credentials from production code will be forgotten and as a result, a default login for hackers is available.

Comment: You're doing seventeen things wrong that have nothing to do with this question.  Thank you for shopping StackOverflow.

Comment: @Michael: If someone wants to enter the program without password, he simply enters the app without password. Hard-coded or not. Maybe you should take a look at reverse engineering. And a look at "Another Java Decompiler" if I'm right.

Comment: @Michael: Except when you encrypt a part of the app. And the algorithm to decrypt makes use of an entered password....

Comment: @Martijn: If the user has access to the progam itself or it is running with users rights, the user can reverse engineer. It is possible that the user only is a client which is not running the program with his own user rights. So he cannot reverse enginering. But nevertheless it is never a good choice to code a password in the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The char[] doesn't equals to a String. Try to create a String out of it:

```
new String(password).equals("test")
```

Comment: -1 If it was a good idea for the password field to use a string for the password, it would not bother using a char array.

Comment: I suggested only to convert the char-array into a String, not to change the input-field.

Answer (score 6):

You might want

```
new String(password).equals("test")
```

instead. Comparing array to string makes little sense.

Comment: -1 If it was a good idea for the password field to use a string for the password, it would not bother using a char array.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: Explain, why the String should be a bad solution (besides that the answer only suggests to convert the array for the check).

Comment: @Mnementh The only case I know is when you store hashed passwords in database: you usually can't convert them to string. That's not the case here, however.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The part where you check the password is wrong. `password` is a `char[]`. So you have to change the way of checking it:

**Way 1**: Create a String of it

```
if (new String(password).equals("test"))
```

**Way 2**: Iterate over the array and check char by char:

```
public boolean checkPassword(char[] pass, String correctPass)
{
    if (pass.length != correctPass.length()) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++)
    {
        if (pass[i] != correctPass.charAt(i)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And in your if-statement

```
if (checkPassword(password, "test"))
```

Comment: You also should zero out the char array.

Comment: Would look simpler with `Arrays.equals`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 'password' is an array - doing an equals on it is a reference comparison. Convert it to a String and do equals on that.

EDIT: It looks like this is the "proper" way:

```
private static boolean isPasswordCorrect(char[] input) {
    boolean isCorrect = true;
    char[] correctPassword = { 'b', 'u', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'o', 'o' };

    if (input.length != correctPassword.length) {
        isCorrect = false;
    } else {
        isCorrect = Arrays.equals (input, correctPassword);
    }

    //Zero out the password.
    Arrays.fill(correctPassword,'0');

    return isCorrect;
}
```

From the [java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html).

Comment: @Pete - Enlighten me. Why is it a bad idea then?

Comment: @Pete - Maybe you can post your solution. Since it looks like everyone here is wrong? :)

Comment: @Pete - NM, I think I get it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Because objects of type String are immutable -- the contents of the string cannot be changed or overwritten after use

Answer (score 1):

```
password.equals("test")
```

will always return `false`, because `test` as String  and `password` as char[] are different classes. They can never be equal.

But you can use the [char[] representation of the String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) and check the arrays on equality via
[boolean java.utilArrays.equals(char[] a,char[] b)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(char%5B%5D,%20char%5B%5D)):

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(password,"test".toCharArray())
```

In real life you may won't have password as String but already as char[].
Then of course you can directly use it in `Arrays#equals`.